# Как отключить внешний файл.py из другого python-файла

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Есть вк и телеграм боты, запущенные как демоны на linux. Я хочу сделать для них админ-панель (тоже в виде бота).

Для начала нужно перезагружать ботов т.е. просто убивать процесс, чтобы ОС заново запускала исполняемые файлы.

Как убить процесс с ботом?

Comment: пусть каждый бот при старте создает уникальный файл с PID процесса, а админка читает эти файлы. PID можно получить с помощью `os.getpid()`. "прибить" процесс по PID - `os.kill`. А если в ботах реализовать реакцию на прерывания([signal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html)), например по USR1, то будет возможен "мягкий" перезапуск.

Comment: можно и по `ps -ef` искать еще